# Can I combine these functions into one streamlined function?

Tags: javascript

I am swapping out background images on click for several different instances, and also only targeting screens at 991px and above. Can I create one, streamlined function or make this more concise/better?

```
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 991px)')
const infraTab1 = document.querySelector(".content1")
const infraTab2 = document.querySelector(".content2")
const infraTab3 = document.querySelector(".content3")
const infraTab4 = document.querySelector(".content4")
const infrastructure = document.querySelector(".infrastructure")

if (mediaQuery.matches) {

  infraTab1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    infrastructure.style.backgroundImage = "url(img1.jpg)";
  })
}
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
  infraTab2.addEventListener("click", function () {
    infrastructure.style.backgroundImage = "url(img2.jpg)";
  })
}
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
  infraTab3.addEventListener("click", function () {
    infrastructure.style.backgroundImage = "url(img3.jpg)";
  })
}
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
  infraTab4.addEventListener("click", function () {
    infrastructure.style.backgroundImage = "url(img4.jpg)";
  })
}
```

Comment: Put everything into one if-statement, rather than separate identical ones. Put your tabs into one NodeList with `infraTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".content1, .content2, .content3, .content4)`

Comment: You could write a loop that counts from 1 to 4, and for each value, get the appropriate tab & add the appropriate event listener by building the strings with the number in it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, This is the solution which you want

```
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 991px)')
const infraTab1 = document.querySelector(".content1")
const infraTab2 = document.querySelector(".content2")
const infraTab3 = document.querySelector(".content3")
const infraTab4 = document.querySelector(".content4")
const infrastructure = document.querySelector(".infrastructure")

if (mediaQuery.matches) {
    setEventOn(infraTab1, infrastructure,  "img1.jpg");
    setEventOn(infraTab2, infrastructure,  "img2.jpg");
    setEventOn(infraTab3, infrastructure,  "img3.jpg");
    setEventOn(infraTab4, infrastructure,  "img4.jpg");
}

function setEventOn(element, infra,  img){
    infraTab4.addEventListener("click", function () {
        infra.style.backgroundImage = "url("+img+")";
    })
}
```